# Deserialize xml hierarchy to field

Tags: java, xml, jackson, deserialization

I have xml file that I need to deserialize into java object. There is one complication. I need to deserialize `<properties>/<id></id></properties>` into just a field in result object:

```
<root>
    <properties>
        <id>Some id</id>
    </properties>
    <name>Alex</name>
</root>

class Entity {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}
```

I am using Jackson for this, but it is not mandatory to stick with it. Any ideas, how to deserialize that xml hierarchy into a field?